# My website's contact form is correctly centered when viewing it from the PC, but it doesn't work on the iPad. What do I do?

Tags: html, ipad

It looks great on the PC's browsers and smartphones as well, but when I see it on the iPad, the contact form isn't centered and the browser "cuts" it a little bit. My website is

www.wonderr.com.br/site

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you be able to include a reproducible sample of code here (or in a jsfiddle) that does the same thing? See stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

i think that is for his mediaQueries

With mediaQueries in your file of css can manipulate the sizes of his elements depending on the device where it is displayed.

For Example:

```
@media screen and(min-width:780px) and (max-width:1024px){Here the CSS for PC}

@media screen and(min-width:480px) and (max-with:780px){ Here the CSS for Tablets}

@media screen and(max-width:480px){ for Cellphones}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get better answers if you create a smaller reproduction of the problem so people don't have to wade through your entire site to figure out what you're talking about.

But I'm seeing at certain widths the contact form is off the left edge of the browser viewport.  This can happen in a desktop browser as well as an ipad if the browser width is right.  It seems to be related to this css rule.

```
.full-map .container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -585px
}
```

I can't give you a line number, because it's in a minified css document.  That negative left margin is pulling the form off the edge of the screen.  It's really hard for me to guess what the correct solution is though, as the css seems to be kind of a mess.